# SpriteKit: touchesEnded/ mouseUp sent to released object

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, scenekit

I have the problem that touchesEnded (on iOS) or mouseUp (on macOS) is still called on released objects when the touch/click was started before the release. This behavior is causing crashes in my project. I made a stripped down program with SceneKit and a SpriteKit overlay but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I've started with the SceneKit game template (iOS or macOS) and I've added two classes:

---

In GameViewController.m at the end of -(void)awakeFromNib I added this:

```
OverlayScene *overlay=[OverlayScene sceneWithSize:self.gameView.frame.size];// init the overlay
[overlay setupButtons];// create a small GUI menu
[self.gameView setOverlaySKScene:overlay];// add the overlay to the SceneKit view
```

---

Then the two classes
OverlayScene.m:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "Button.h"

@interface OverlayScene : SKScene
-(void)setupButtons;
@end
```

---

OverlayScene.m:

```
#import "OverlayScene.h"
@implementation OverlayScene

-(void)setupButtons{//showing a menu mockup 
    NSLog(@"setupButtons");
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));// seed the RNG
    [self removeAllChildren];//remove all GUI element (only one button or nothing (in the first call)
    Button *b=[[Button alloc] initWithSelector:@selector(setupButtons) onObject:self];// a new button
    b.position=CGPointMake(rand()%300, rand()%300);// just a random position so we can see the change
    [self addChild:b];// finally attach the button to the scene
}

@end
```

---

Button.h:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
@interface Button : SKSpriteNode{
    SEL selector;//the method which is supposed to be called by the button
    __weak id selectorObj;//the object on which the selector is called
}
-(id)initWithSelector:(SEL)s onObject:(__weak id)o;
@end
```

---

Button.m:

```
#import "Button.h"
@implementation Button
-(id)initWithSelector:(SEL)s onObject:(__weak id)o{
    //self=[super initWithColor:[UIColor purpleColor] size:CGSizeMake(200, 60)];//this is the code for iOS
    self=[super initWithColor:[NSColor purpleColor] size:CGSizeMake(200, 60)];// this is for macOS
    selector=s;//keep the selector with the button
    selectorObj=o;
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];//enable touch handling
    return self;
}
//-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{//called on iOS
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event{//called on macOS
    [selectorObj performSelector:selector];//we are calling the method which was given during the button initialization
}
@end
```

---

When you click on the button it gets removed (and dealloced by arc) as expected and a new one is created. Everything is fine as long as you keep holding down the mouse button. When you release it the app crashes because that mouseUp event is sent to the removed button:
[image]

Comment: yikes your variable names makes it very hard to read,  but why are you calling setup buttons inside of your selector?  You are removing your buttons with the remove all, thus getting your errors

Comment: This code is radically shortened to focus on the problem. In my original app I am showing different menus (which are dynamically generated) and not always the same like in the example but the problem is the same. For the purpose of showing the problem it doesn't matter what is actually shown. Initially I had two different menus in the example, between you could switch back and forth. Also I think the variable names are ok because there are no more than 3 variables per function and the functions are very short. Now to the removal, how else am I supposed to remove all nodes?

Comment: Name length Ok for you maybe. Not people helping you.  I dont know what you are trying to do in the code here, but switching to another menu, you shouls make sure you switch first, then remove when all is clear

Comment: When I store that button as an instance variable (Button *btt;) and then remove it with [btt removeFromParent]; instead of [self removeAllChildren]; the behavior is the same.

Comment: Of course, you are removing a button that should not be removed,  it is like murdering somebody and expecting them to show up to work a few minutes later

Comment: I've added some comments to make the code more clear. I am removing this button because otherwise it just stack up on the memory without a use. Note that the menu is generated based on user settings and the current situation. I can't just hide it and show it again later. I am expecting the button to be removed from the memory and click/touch tracking to be stopped. I am not expecting this removed button to be working again.

Comment: If you could provide a project ill take a look at it tonight

Comment: That would be really nice. All you need for the project is the SceneKit template and the code i posted above. Sure I could also upload/send you Xcode project files.

Comment: OK here is what is happening,  mouseUp is looking for button, but button does not exist, looks like there is a defect in mouseUp code that it does not validate if a button exists before firing an event on it.  You are going to have to retain it somehow, and remove it at the end up update

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. It is strange that mouseDragged isn't when you move the mouse after the removal.

Comment: it is when you move the mouse after the removal, not sure what you are talking about?

Comment: There is a word missing... mouseDragged isn't fired after the removal but mouseUp is.

Comment: mouseDragged is not suppose to be fired,  neither is mouseUp if the object is nil, but there is a bug with scene kit with sprite kit overlay apparently,  I saw another issue with this happen, but the code was not clear and I assumed it was only sprite kit, so I will find it tomorrow and tell that user as well.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I wasn't sure if this was a bug. In those situations it is me at modt times who is doing something wrong.

Comment: well technically, it is both LOL,  you should not be removing things from your sprite kit scene til the end of the update, for reasons like you are witnessing.  This is mostly my opinion of course, but from a design standpoint, it only makes sense to kill at the end of the update because I like to treat each update as a frozen moment in time, evaluate that moment, then when ready to unfreeze time, make the changes.

Comment: Ok, I have applied what you wrote. Instead of directly removing the button I only made it hidden. Now I added the update method which is called by SpriteKit and in there I removed all hidden Nodes. So instead of removing the button on the mouseDown event it is removed in the update method. The app is still crashing on mouseUp.

Comment: I wouldn't do that,  just use an array called killSprites,  when you want a sprite to die, add it to the array,  then call removeFromParent on those sprites,  this allows you to hide sprites without killing them

Comment: Already tried that too, same behavior. My current solution is to move the buttons to the hidden node 'nodesToRemove' and clear that node only once in a minute.

Comment: oh yeah  i guess mouseUp would have to be a different update cycle

Comment: Perhaps you could override `[buttonclass removeFromParentNode]` and make it set some sort of bool var to "yes" and make the node invisible. then in buttonclass' mouseup you could call `[super removeFromParentNode]` if the bool var flag is yes. After this, instead of calling `[self removeAllChildren]` in setupbuttons, you could iterate through all the children calling `[child removeFromParentNode]`

Comment: but you might get memory issues seeing how this stores all the nodes until mouseup

Comment: It also would be helpful if you would give us an example of why you would need to do this removing button thing. please.

Comment: Sometimes instead of finding a solution to your code you have to find a solution to the logic behind it! Good Luck!

Comment: I've already implemented a similar workaround and it is working but it just feels wrong. I am removing those buttons because those menus are dynamically generated based on the user settings, the situation and the data which is not hard-coded. Why should I keep those buttons? They would just stack up in the memory. How else would you implement this?