# SpriteKit as SceneKit's overlay SKShapeNode Crash

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, scenekit

I having a strange Crash in SKOverlayScene
I do not have the same crash when I am using SKScene Alone not as overlay.

This is Console output.

**Edit**
The crash never happens if address sanitizer is available.

> malloc: *** error for object 0x610000670e00: Invalid pointer dequeued
>   from free list
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

May someone help please?

Overlay SKSceme Code below:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if(self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        //[self setBackgroundColor:[SKColor greenColor]];

        _selectionNode = [SKShapeNode node]; // iVar
        [_selectionNode setLineWidth:1];
        [_selectionNode setStrokeColor:[SKColor whiteColor]];
        [_selectionNode setFillColor:[SKColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.5 blue:1 alpha:0.2]];
        ///[_selectionNode setZPosition:CGFLOAT_MAX-1];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if(_selectionNode)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            @autoreleasepool
            {
                CGPoint point = [theEvent locationInNode:self];
                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(_selectionOrigin.x, _selectionOrigin.y, point.x - _selectionOrigin.x, point.y - _selectionOrigin.y);

                CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, NULL);
                if(path)
                {
                    [_selectionNode setPath:path]; //SIGABRT is sometimes shown here.
                    CGPathRelease(path);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    [super mouseDragged:theEvent];
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if(_selectionNode)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            [self addChild:_selectionNode];
            _selectionOrigin = [theEvent locationInNode:self];
        });
    }

    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
}

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if(_selectionNode)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            [_selectionNode removeFromParent];
            [_selectionNode setPath:nil];
        });
    }
    [super mouseUp:theEvent];
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Setting a BreakPoint in malloc_error_break show the following

> libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_error_break:
>   ->  0x7fffba83e147 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
>       0x7fffba83e148 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
>       0x7fffba83e14b <+4>:  nop
>       0x7fffba83e14c <+5>:  nopl   (%rax)
>       0x7fffba83e150 <+9>:  popq   %rbp
>       0x7fffba83e151 <+10>: retq

Coming from various threads each time.

**Edit 3**
The crash is not recreating when using OpenGL Renderer.

But I really want to use Metal because it really gives twice better performance the only problem is this weird crash... is there anything I can do ?

**Edit 4**

I substitute SKShapeNode with SKSpriteNode
and the problem is seems to be solved.

-- This smells like an Apple bug with: Metal SceneKit + SpriteKit and SKShapeNode.

I won't file any bug reports since Apple just ignores my reports.

Comment: This has been answered numerous of times on here,  mouseUp is being called on the overlay, but the object (_selectionNode perhaps) no longer exists.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Why isnt it exists ? I never dispose it. Also the crash is inside mouse dragged.Why it doesnt happen with OpenGL or SKSpriteNode ?

Comment: `[_selectionNode removeFromParent];` is happening, (on the main thread? is mouseUp not on main thread?) so that is why I am guessing.  It could be something else,  but I bet if you commented the `super.mouseUp`, your code will not crash. (You are suppose to call this, but like I said, it is calling mouseUp somewhere that does not exist in your overlay)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon _selectionNode is an iVar and it is retained. so removeFromParent won't dispose it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Also it crashes even if I comment all the super calls

Comment: you are missing the point,  I do not know what is causing the problem, I do not have your code, I am explaining why the problem is happening.

Comment: wait, is this code the SKScene or the SCNScene,  I was thinking SCNScene but this looks like the SKScene,  my apologies on that.  See this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935505/spritekit-touchesended-mouseup-sent-to-released-object for more info

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I am on the SKScene, the SO question you linked is a different problem,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127010/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-user3351949).

Comment: no it is not, you are going from scene kit over lay to sprite kit overlay, that is the exact same problem

Comment: @Knight0fDragon No, it is different problem please reread both questions.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon --  In the linked question, the one who takes mouse events is the Button (Which is some kind of `SKNode`), which can be deallocated at any time.
In my scenario: `SKScene` and only `SKScene` is getting the Mouse Events, and it is never gets deallocated, as well as `_selectioNode` is never deallocated

Comment: SCNScene is always getting mouse events, it just calls the super without you knowing if you do not override it, and passes it to the overlay.  Now I see your problem, it is in mouseDragged you are saying, so you are hitting an issue before you hit the one I describe.  My apologies.  Did you try Xcode 8.1 yet?  people are saying the allocation issue is fixed

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Appstore Doesn't tell me there is an Update :(

Comment: you need to go to developer.apple.com and get the GM version

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Then I will live with `SKSpriteNode` selection version which is not crashing for me until there will be an official release.

Comment: that is good,  you should avoid SKShapeNodes at all costs anyway lol  even apple says use it sparingly (caused they f#cked them up badly)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yeah I already fired a whole book of bug reports with `SKShapeNode` the problem with knowing this is -- now i tend to assume that there are gazzilion bugs with this, but maybe somewhen I have the bug in my code and i tend to blame Apple :)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Can you help me with this Question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297443/scenekit-with-spritekit-intersection-of-nodes yu already commented on this,  but there must be a way to achieve so

Comment: @Knight0fDragon if you use a texture for the outline of a SKShapeNode, in the latest versions of Xcode and iOS, with no fill, it's actually incredibly performant. I think this forces it to rasterise. Still has terrible performance for any animation of SKShapeNode values.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I discovered is that using overlaySKScene in SceneKit results in a lot of random crashes like this. Also note that when using SKScene as an overlaySKScene that call backs from actions are not on the Main Thread (whereas they are when used as a stand-alone scene).

My solution was to use a normal SKScene. Just add an SKView as a subview to your SCNScene and call presentScene to use SKScene in the normal way. That stopped the crashing for me.